# Making Renders look like Digital Paintings

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes

I've seen a lot of 3d renders that really don't look rendered at all, most notably a lot of [Gleb Alexandrov](http://glebalexandrov.com/)'s work. I'm getting an idea it has to do with multiple factors including post processing and manipulating individual passes in the compositor, but is there any good tutorials out there that explain better?

Best Regards

Simon

Comment: The technique is called *Color grading*, so search for that. But be very careful with it, because it can make or break the result. You should use it to add atmosphere and adjust the feeling of image, avoid using it just for cool factor or for hiding that your materials and lighting are not setup correctly. It's like Instagram filters, it can easily become a cancer.

Comment: Your question is not clear or seems too broad. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post and add some example images of what you want to do and clarify  what specific part of the process you need help with.